# Whirlpool Dishwasher leaks from the air vent

Tags: doors, vent, leaks, air

My Whirlpool Dishwasher WDF520PADM7 (2019) has the a passive style air vent on the upper left corner of the door (passive means there is no solenoid or fan). Water leaks from air vent assembly through the door panels to the floor on the left side of the door during washing cycle. The vent assembly is very clean. Replaced rubber gasket (6) makes no difference. I then replaced the whole vent assembly (5,6,7) to no avail. I now believe the seating hole on the door is too big to hold the vent assembly tight enough. I was wondering if somebody ever got air vent leaks fixed. Let me stress it again: the air vent assembly is very clean. I read a lot of answers saying how they clean the air vent to stop leaking. This is definitely not in my case.[image: Whirlpool Dishwasher Door Assembly][image: Air Vent Assembly]

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10701/what-is-the-cause-of-dishwasher-vent-leak/197940#197940) first mentions cleaning, but offers two other possibilities. Have you addressed both of them?

Comment: Those answers didn't work in my case. See my original post: 1) the vent assembly was very clean; 2) tried new seal didn't work; 3) Tried new vent assembly didn't help.

Comment: When I got a new dishwasher I had a similar issue that was resolved by re-arranging the dishes/pots inside the dishwasher. Apparently my longtime arrangement with mixing bowls on top was redirecting the spray toward the door vent area.

Comment: Just had a look, turns out ours has one as well. However, this model has a round metal plate a few mm in front, which acts as a splash guard. I'm not sure how handy you are, but you could try applying one (either from a different model that fits, or making one from scratch from a thick, thermal resistant plastic type).

Comment: I finally stop the leaking by applying a beats of plumber's putty around outer ring of the air vent where it inserts to the inner door panel. I guess the surface on the door around opening develops some imperfects. The thickness of the rubber gasket is not enough to stop the water from leaking out.